# Circle divided into sectors by drawing lines between $n$ points

Tags: combinatorics

For those of you aware, this is the classic "$n$ points seems to give $2^{n-1}$ sectors" from $n = 2$ to $5$ but when you get $n = 6$ it splits it into $31$ sectors.

Place $n$ points around a circle and draw lines connecting each point to each other (the points must be placed so that there is no intersection of $3$ or more lines). How many sectors is the circle divided into?

I've been trying to solve the problem using $V - E + F = 1$ but I'm having trouble finding an explicit formula for the number of edges and vertices.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas) has your answer.

Solving the recurrence there gives a closed form:

\begin{align*}
  {f}_{n}=\frac{\left( n-1\right) \,n\,\left( {n}^{2}-5\,n+18\right) }{24}+1
\end{align*}

That page also has the method you are seeking, and the formula without simplification is actually:

\begin{align*}
  {f}_{n}=\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{2}+1
\end{align*}